# Handling file attributes in python 3.0

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am currently developing an application in python 3 and i need to be able to hide certain files from the view of people. i found a few places that used the win32api and win32con but they don't seem to exist in python 3.

Does anyone know if this is possible without rolling back or writing my own attribute library in C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=78018&package_id=79063&release_id=661475) Python Extensions for Windows.  Recently released for Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) to directly access functions from kernel32.dll.

The function you're looking for is `windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesA`